# Use Apache HttpService in Android SDK 22

Tags: android, apache

I want to use HttpService in Android for hosting a simple Web Server. When I set the target SDK as 23, and follow instructions here: https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client, I am able to use HttpService class without any problems.

But I want to do this with target SDK 22. When I try to do that, the code compiles but AndroidStudio keeps giving "deprecated" warnings. Is there any way to avoid that? If its possible to do with SDK 23, then why not with SDK 22?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to use HttpClient in Android for hosting a simple Web Server.

HttpClient is for implementing the client side of an HTTP connection. I am not aware that it is particularly useful for implementing an HTTP server.

> Is there any way to avoid that?

No, other than to stop using Android's long-since-discontinued fork of HttpClient and use [the official library from Apache](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/android-port.html). Google has been telling developers to stop using the built-in HttpClient fork for quite some time. It was only with API Level 22 and up that they started enforcing it more.

Comment: Apologies, I meant HttpService instead of HttpClient. Can you take a look at the question again? Thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: @Bonton255: It doesn't really change my answer. If you want to use `HttpService`, use Apache's official up-to-date implementation.

Comment: I had already tried what you suggest (adding compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1' to dependency), but that doesn't change anything. HttpService still points to < Android API 22 Platform > and still shows it as deprecated.

Comment: @Bonton255: Yeah, `HttpService` appears to be part of Apache's HttpComponents, not strictly HttpClient. Their project is a bit confusing. I do not know if there is an Android-friendly HttpComponents, though [this looks promising](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html).

Comment: @mark: that link is essentially saying the same thing as the earlier link you shared.

Comment: @Bonton255: I though that the artifact name was different, but it's not -- my apologies. I have no idea if there is an Android-friendly `HttpService` implementation from Apache. That being said, *please* don't use the built-in one, as heaven only knows what bugs are floating around in it that Google will never fix. If you're implementing a server, it is crucial to use one that is being maintained, particularly for security fixes.

Comment: Figured out the solution. The link you gave above also points to the copy of HttpComponents with a changed namespace cz.msebera.android.I used that and all works fine now! For anyone else facing this problem, the only solution as of today is to use https://github.com/smarek/httpclient-android/wiki/Project-Introduction